# How to use libxml2 with CMake?

Tags: cmake, libxml2

I am using CLion editor (with CMake) for my C project,
I've never used an external library though,
my question is how do I link an external lib (for ex. libxml2) to my project?
I've seen some questions similar to this but none worked for me.
My project is compiled on Windows, and I have libxml .dll, include, and .lib files(binaries for Windows).

Edit: My CMakeLists.txt file after the answer suggested:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(time_table)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES
    course.c
    course.h
    day.h
    defines.h
    find_tables.c
    find_tables.h
    item.h
    parse_info.c
    parse_info.h
    table.c
    table.h
    time_table.c grades.c grades.h)

link_libraries(C:/Users/Gal/Desktop/time_table/libxml2-2.7.8.win32/lib)
add_executable(time_table ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(time_table libxml2)
```

and this is what I get:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 1.1.1\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\Gal\.clion11\system\cmake\generated\2eda76ff\2eda76ff\Debug --target time_table -- -j 8
[ 14%] Linking C executable time_table.exe
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibxml2
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [time_table.exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles\time_table.dir\build.make:225: recipe for target 'time_table.exe' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/time_table.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/time_table.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/time_table.dir/rule' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/time_table.dir/rule] Error 2
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What exactly you tried?

Comment: I tried using: link_directories(), and target_link_libraries() with no success.
Maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Answer (score 6):

There is a key work for libraries installed on your machine.  `<lib_name>_INCLUDE_DIR` and `<lib_name>_LIBRARIES` once you have done `find_package`. This works for me.

```
find_package(LibXml2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/<my_stuff> ${LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_executable(<my_exe> <my_source_files>)
target_link_libraries(<my_exe> ${LIBXML2_LIBRARIES})
```

*---- Just a note for your curiosity ----*

If you ever needed to build (1) a (static) library of your calculations, maybe reusable, and (2) an executable that uses that library and LIBXML2, do this.

```
find_package(LibXml2 REQUIRED)

# add a calculation library: file "lib<mycalc>.a"
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/<your header files folder> ${LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_library(<mycalc> STATIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/<your src files folder>)
target_link_libraries(<mycalc> ${LIBXML2_LIBRARIES}) 

# add the executable: file <my_exe>
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/<your header files folder> ${LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_executable(<my_exe> <your exe src files>)
target_link_libraries(<my_exe> <mycalc> ${LIBXML2_LIBRARIES})
```

Answer (score 3):

With moderns CMake (version 3.2 or newer), it got much easier:

1. Search for the library. CMake has an [according find module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindLibXml2.html), thus it boils down to

   ```
   find_package(LibXml2 REQUIRED)
   ```
2. Then you can link the library it to your target `foo`

   ```
   target_link_libraries(foo PUBLIC LibXml2::LibXml2)
   ```

That's it folks! No fiddling around with headers and libraries, all done automatically.

If you have not installed the library, you might want to set `LibXml2_DIR` to the location where LibXml2 is located, i.e., by passing `-DLibXml2_DIR=C:\software\libxml2` to your CMake call. That will help CMake finding LibXml2.

Comment: Is there a way to set this in the cmakelists.txt file? Rather than passing it in?

Comment: this should be the right answer, as it's the only truly portable way of doing it, and also takes case of include paths. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that full path to the library(`.lib`) can be expressed as

```
<library_dir>/<library_name>.lib
```

For *compile* executable, which uses this library, you need:

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
link_libraries(<library_dir>)

add_excutable(<my_exe> ..)
target_link_libraries(<my_exe> <library_name>)
```

For *use*(*run*) compiled executable, you need to have `<library_name>.dll` either under one of the directory, listed in the `PATH` environment variable, or within same directory with executable.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I still get compilation error.
I put my CMake file on the question, maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: So full path to you library file is `C:/Users/Gal/Desktop/time_table/libxml2-2.7.8.win32/lib/libxml2.lib` (filename contains `lib` prefix), isn't it? In case of `xml2.lib` file you should use `xml2` in `target_link_libraries()` call.

Comment: Yes, file name is indeed libxml2.lib

Comment: I added " " to the path and now get the following error:
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 1.1.1\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\Gal\.clion11\system\cmake\generated\2eda76ff\2eda76ff\Debug --target time_table -- -j 8
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** No rule to make target '/libxml2/lib', needed by 'time_table.exe'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/time_table.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/time_table.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/time_table.dir/rule' failed`

Comment: I do not understand, where you add  " " and why. As for failed linking, it may be a result of incompatible type of library file(libxml2.lib can be built with Visual Studio, but you build your project with minGW), but I am not sure with it. You may try to link using full path to the library file: `target_link_libraries(time_table "C:/Users/Gal/Desktop/time_table/libxml2-2.7.8.win32/lib/libxml2.lib")`

Answer (score 0):

there are 32bit and 64bit version of `libxml2`, to be found [here](ftp://ftp.zlatkovic.com/libxml).

you can put them below the `PATH` - or the `C:\Windows` directory.