# Libxml2: static or not static

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compilation, libxml2

My question is quite simple: Can we compile statically when using the libxml2?
Actually, I spent an all day searching how it was possible to do that, but I clearly failed.
When I run the following command line:

```
gcc -o exec `xml2-config --cflags` io1.c `xml2-config --libs` -static
```

I get a bunch of errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.a(nanohttp.o) : dans la fonction « xmlNanoHTTPConnectHost » :
(.text+0xb3b): avertissement : Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x9ba): avertissement : Using 'gethostbyname' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/bin/ld : /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.a(xpath.o) : dans la fonction « xmlXPathStringEvalNumber.part.0 » :
(.text+0x1f71) : référence indéfinie vers « pow »
/usr/bin/ld : (.text+0x1ffb) : référence indéfinie vers « pow »
...
```

When I use `cmake` it is stranger because I can compile but the executable does not work.

```
find_package(LibXml2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# create an executable
add_executable(conspiler ${SRCS} ${HEADERS})

target_compile_options(conspiler PUBLIC -std=c++11 -Wall -lz -O3 -lgmpxx -lgmp)
target_link_libraries (conspiler -lz -O3 -lgmpxx -lgmp libpatoh.a ${LIBXML2_LIBRARIES} -static)

install(PROGRAMS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/conspiler
DESTINATION bin
RENAME ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}-conspiler)
```

I get (in french, but that means the executable cannot be found oO):

```
bash: ./conspiler: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

Best regards,
JM

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Telling gcc directly to link a library statically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578484/telling-gcc-directly-to-link-a-library-statically)

Comment: Not exactly, I do not have problems when I create static library in general. With the library libxml it seems it is not possible to do that. I think it is because the library libxml2 is not static, but I really need to construct a static executable. I tried to follow this post: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047602/how-to-use-libxml2-with-cmake> but that does not help, actually I do not understand everything ...

Comment: There's `libxml2.a` in your error messages, so you do have a static version of libxml2. What happens if you compile with `-Wl,-Bstatic $(xml2-config --libs) -Wl,-Bdynamic`?

Comment: I tested `gcc -o exec $(xml2-config --cflags) io1.c -Wl,-Bstatic $(xml2-config --libs) -Wl,-Bdynamic` and I got almost the same error.

Comment: It is very strange, I use make VERBOSE=1 to print out the command line and I got something like `/usr/bin/c++  -O3 -DNDEBUG  -rdynamic CMakeFiles/conspiler.dir/src/parser/XCSP3Manager.cc.o -o conspiler   -L/home/jm/Works/ConSPiler/3rdparty/patoh  -Wl,-rpath,/home/jm/Works/ConSPiler/3rdparty/patoh -lz -O3 -lgmpxx -lgmp -Wl,-Bstatic -lpatoh -Wl,-Bdynamic -Wno-class-memaccess -lxml2 -static`(I remove a lot of .o files to shorten the command line). And when I run conspiler I get: `bash: ./conspiler: No file or directory of this type`. I compiled and install libxml2 locally and that does not help.

Comment: Don't add `-static`, only the `-Wl,-B` switches.

Comment: If this doesn't work, please post the output of `xml2-config --libs` and `xml2-config --cflags`. If you're using a libxml2 distro package, tell us the exact OS and package version. If you built libxml2 from source, tell us the exact library version.

Comment: I removed `-static` and that compile. But when I test on another compute that does not work (`./exec: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by ./exec)`). `xml2-config --libs --cflags` returns `-L/home/jm/Works/ConSPiler/3rdparty/xmlinst/lib -lxml2 -lz -lm
-I/home/jm/Works/ConSPiler/3rdparty/xmlinst/include/libxml2`.